# Segmentation fault: 11 of Maze problem in c++

Tags: c++

The maze is represented by a 2x2 vector where a 0 represents a blocked and 1
represents a free cell.
The goal is to find if there is a path between start and end, so I tried to recursive the function after judge whether the end can trace back to it last point. And if I visited each point, I change the point value to 2, and if I visited the start, I change the point value to 3.Finally, I check the start point, if it is 3,return true, else return false.
But It shows the Segmentation fault: 11

and if I Commented out code：

```
if(input[e.first+1][e.second] == 1 && e.first+1 < input[0].size()) {
      if (e.first+1 == s.first && e.second == s.second){
        input[e.first+1][e.second] = 3;
      }else{
        e.first += 1;
        input[e.first][e.second] = 2;
        maze(input, s, e);
      }
    }
```

The answer is 
0
1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 
2 0 0 0 0 
2 2 2 2 2 
1
3 1 0 0 0 
2 0 1 1 1 
2 2 0 0 1 
2 2 0 0 1 
2 2 2 2 2

The function:

```
bool Solution::maze(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& input, std::pair<int,int> s, std::pair<int,int> e){
  input[.first][e.second] = 2;
  if(e.first>=0 && e.second>=0 && e.first<input[0].size() && e.second<input.size()){
    if(input[e.first][e.second-1] == 1 && e.second-1 >= 0){
      if (e.first == s.first && e.second-1 == s.second){
        input[e.first][e.second-1] = 3;
      }else{
        e.second -= 1;
        input[e.first][e.second] = 2;
        maze(input, s, e);
      }
    }

    if(input[e.first+1][e.second] == 1 && e.first+1 < input[0].size()) {
      if (e.first+1 == s.first && e.second == s.second){
        input[e.first+1][e.second] = 3;
      }else{
        e.first += 1;
        input[e.first][e.second] = 2;
        maze(input, s, e);
      }
    }
    if(input[e.first-1][e.second] == 1 && e.first-1 >= 0){
      if (e.first-1 == s.first && s.second == e.second){
        input[e.first-1][e.second] = 3;
      }else{
        e.first -= 1;
        input[e.first][e.second] = 2;
        maze(input, s, e);
      }
    }
    if (input[e.first][e.second+1] == 1 && e.second+1 < input.size()){
       if(e.first == s.first && e.second+1 == s.second){
        input[e.first][e.second+1] = 3;
      }else{
        e.second += 1;
        input[e.first][e.second] = 2;
        maze(input, s, e);
      }
    }


  }
  if(input[s.first][s.second] == 3){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }

}
```

Main function:

```
int main() {
 Solution solution;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> input = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                                         {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                                         {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                                         {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                         {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
  std::pair<int,int> s(1,2);
  std::pair<int,int> e(4,4);

  std::cout << solution.maze(input, s, e) << std::endl;
  for(auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it){
    std::vector<int> n = *it;
    for(auto it1 = n.begin(); it1 != n.end(); ++it1){
      int n1 = *it1;
      std::cout<< n1<< " ";
    }
    std::cout <<  std::endl;
  }

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> input1 = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                                          {1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                                          {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                                          {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                                          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
  std::pair<int,int> s1(0,0);
  std::pair<int,int> e1(4,4);

  std::cout << solution.maze(input1, s1, e1) << std::endl;
  for(auto it = input1.begin(); it != input1.end(); ++it){
    std::vector<int> n = *it;
    for(auto it1 = n.begin(); it1 != n.end(); ++it1){
      int n1 = *it1;
      std::cout<< n1<< " ";
    }
    std::cout <<  std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Compile in debug mode, run your debugger, and examine the values of your variables when it crashes. Because as is this is very difficult code to read and follow. Some comments would help. Reducing it to a [example] would help further. Using meaningful variable names would also be helpful. I want to help you, but this is just a major endeavor to read at the moment.

Comment: The comparison with `size` should be done first, before accessing the array.  And you're comparing with the wrong sizes: `e.first` should be `input.size()`, `e.second` with `input[0].size` (although that subscript should depend on `e.first`, not `0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault is probably due to one of your array loops calling an index out of range. When you’re trying to access input[first][second] and one of those is being incremented or decremented like input[first+1] it could be out of bounds